# GDAL freezes when merging large images

Tags: gdal

I am using GDAL 1.11.3 to merge about 9000 tif of satellite images (for a total of 60 GB) to create a huge image, representing the whole Mediterranean, which I will then need to transform into XYZ tiles for my TileServer. These tiffs have different projections, so I transform them all into my projection:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -r average -dstalpha %mypath%!infile! %mypath%!outfile!
```

When I launch the merge, the application freezes after a few hours. Maybe the 60GB of final image needs to be loaded into RAM, running out of it?

```
python3 -m gdal_merge -ot Byte -of GTiff -o c:\merged.tif --optfile c:\tiffsList.txt
```

Is this the right way to process these tiffs to build a mosaic?

Comment: Yes, trying to put that much data into one tiff has probably resulted in running out of memory. gdal_merge is going to try to create a single tiff not tiles, so you might want to look into different functions instead (gdal2tiles?).

Comment: Make a virtual raster layer from the input layers instead of a physical merge. `gdal_translate` is the command. VRT is the output format. Maybe you can make files from the virtual layer instead.

Comment: For the part "Make a virtual raster layer from the input layers" mentioned by @wingnut, use `gdalbuildvrt` utility https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html

Comment: @ThomasG77 - thanks for the correction. I hope it solves his problem.

Comment: @ycartwhelen, yes thank you, I know it, I just omitted the last line to build the mosaic.

Comment: @wingnut thank you. I also tried to do the virtual layuer before, but I couldn't build the mosaic without graphic errors. So do you advise me to transform all the TIFFs into the same projection first and then load it into the virtual layer and then from that layer build the mosaic?

Comment: I would definitely warp them all to the same projection as it only needs to be done once. Otherwise it would need to be done every time the image was loaded.

Comment: Big images should be created as tiled. By default they are created as striped, each stripe containing a few pixel rows. When the rows contain thousands of pixels the resulting image gets hard to handle if the whole image is not loaded into memory.